# asp.net mvc5 scaffolding Unable to retrive metadata for ...Ambiguous match found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Problem: When I want to create controller from EF codefirst context it give me this error:

```
There was an error running the selected code generator.Unable to retrieve  metadata for Model.class name.Ambiguous match found.
```

[See Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gog7g.png)

What I did?

1. As my model data was in seprate assembly I updated all package or downgrade them but nothing happened.
2. Then I merged my Model assembly in Website project but error doesn't resolved.
3. After googleing and many tricks, I created clean project and scaffolding for each class but it seems only one class had this problem.
4. In that class I commented all property and uncomment one by one to find error.
5. Found it! For this property error occurs `public bool ISActive { get; set; }`

I surprised so much and found **how dot net turture  you!!**
What do you think about solution?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming ISActive property to something else such as IsActivated solved my problem.It seems EF scaffolding has problem with this type of naming while cruding.